# Image not showing within <li> till second append call

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list that when I click a button, it populates it with AJAX data, an image basically (this is simplified as the problem is not with AJAX but with the li element).

This is what is being populated into the list:

```
<li class="ind-selector" name="dancing"><a href="#"><img src="screenshot.jpg"></a></li>
```

**The problem**

When I click my call to action, it takes two clicks for this to show and when I debug this within the developer console the image is actually there but at height 0, and so is the `li` item.

When I remove the `li` and just display the image, it works every time.

So my debugging has come down to this: I'm 90% sure it's a problem with the CSS, and this is the CSS I'm using on the list item:

**List item**

```
width: 235px !important;
display: block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin-right: -1px;
```

**Image**

```
width: 235px;
display: block;
height: 100%;
-webkit-filter: brightness(60%);
```

Using the most simplified jQuery append:

```
$(".item-list-slider").append("<li class='ind-modular-selector' name='"+ elem.module_name + "'><a href='#'><img src='" + elem.module_img_src + "' /></a></li>");
```

I'm sure this is a CSS problem but I can't seem to figure it out, has anyone got any ideas? Double clicking on the button to display the image works but the HTML/CSS is exactly the same on both the first click and second!

Comment: can you create fiddle of full example?

Comment: @HiralSuvagya Will do!

Comment: @DennisTurnv: *«when I debug this within the developer console the image is actually there but at height 0»* --> SO! Can we send some live link or [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323243/external-code-snippet-how-to) ? -on second click... Okay. So how you want us to help ?

Comment: There is «minimal code» **and** «not enought code». [HOW TO ASK](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1dpgb0zx/3/ - test it a few times, the double click is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you gave the image `height` in percentage without defining it in the parent, try to give it fixed height or define the `height` at the list item.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  width: 235px !important;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: -1px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 235px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
```

Comment: I didn't even see that height set to 100%. I guess that what coding at 4am does to you. Thank you good sir.